# How do I align the bottom edges of two monitors with xrandr?

Tags: linux, xrandr

I have two outputs that I'd like to use on my laptop:

- LVDS1 – 1366×768
- HDMI1 – 1920×1080

I set my monitors up like so:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --right-of LVDS1
```

This is all well and good, but my laptop sits considerably lower than my external monitor, and with the top edges of the screens being aligned, it makes the jump from one screen to the other rather unintuitive. Is there a way I can align the bottom edges instead? I thought I could use the `--pos` flag to do this, but I have tried and not seen any difference (perhaps I do not know how to use it properly).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
 xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --pos 0x312 --output HDMI1 --auto --pos 1366x0
```

Basically, --pos specifies the position of the upper left corner of the screen in the virtual screen space.  The virtual screen is a screen that spans your entire physical screens. This is a very generic way of specifying screen positions.

You want this configuration:

```
(virtual screen coordinates)
     0       1366                 1366+1920
   
   0           A-----------------------
               |                      |
               |                      |
               |                      |
  x? B---------|         HDMI         |
     |         |                      |
     |  LVDS   |       1920x1080      |
     |1366x768 |                      |
1080 ----------------------------------
```

And you need the coordinates of A and B to use in the `--pos` option.
`x`  is easily solved as 1080 - 768 = 312, so A is at (1366,0) and B is at (0,312).

Therefore, the appropriate --pos options are `--pos 1366x0` for HDMI and `--pos 0x312` for LVDS. You don't have to specify the virtual screen size (anymore), it is resized automatically.

Note that `--pos` can be abused, for exemple to create a hole between your two screens, or create overlapping. Most (all?) WM will not be able to handle that through.

EDIT: oh, you want the other way around, fixed that.

Comment: Heh, figured this out right before you posted. Would you be able to explain how the --pos flag works?

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense! I think you want to replace 1600 with 1080 in your example, though.

Comment: @denaje: Fixed.

Comment: Is there no way to do it within xrandr without using magic values? I'd like to have a script that works regardless of the resolution of the screen I plug in. If not I guess I could extract the values from xrandr's output, but that sounds a little tedious…

Comment: At my case, using i3wm (not sure if relevant) and a 3-monitor layout, I had to use a negative y value for the highest monitor, instead of positive y values for the shorter ones. As an example this didn't work: `--pos 0x240 --pos 1920x0 --pos4480x240`, but this did work: `--pos 0x0 --pos 1920x-240 --pos 4480x0`

Comment: @AlekosDordas I whink you could have used `--primary` to set the monitor that has `0,0`

Answer (score 11):

In addition to @BatchyX's excellent [answer](https://superuser.com/a/485165/112593), an alternative —and IMO more convenient— option could be using [ARandR](https://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/) (which stands for "Another XRandR GUI"):

> ARandR is designed to provide a simple visual front end for XRandR. Relative monitor positions are shown graphically and can be changed in a drag-and-drop way.

You might need to install it first, but it's [available in most distros' repositories](https://repology.org/metapackage/arandr/versions). Here's how it looks for me on LXDE, for a setup with one external monitor connected via VGA, above, and the native (netbook-size) monitor underneath it:

[image: ARandR screenshot]

Comment: One nice thing about it is that it can save scripts with `xrandr` command, allowing you to quickly switch between layouts (e.g. turn off/on one monitor) by simply launching the script. The GUI itself is not very useful nowadays because most DEs provide similar GUI in settings.

Answer (score 4):

If you looking for a drag-and-drop GUI-based solution, I can recommend [ARandR](http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/).

It allows you to set the most important XRandR settings, e.g. screen position and resolution, which then can be saved in form of a shell script that calls `xrandr` with the corresponding parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Someone managed ... hope this helps?

[Dual Screens with aligned bottom edges](http://blog.pault.ag/post/16187362529/dual-screen-setup-with-aligned-bottom-edges)

> #### Dual-screen setup with aligned bottom edges
>
> For the sake of anyone else who’s fighting their screens, I’ve got a script that will do this (but very very slowly)
>
> setup script
>
> ```
> xrandr --output VGA1  --auto
> xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto
> xrandr --output VGA1  --rotate left
> eval "`monconf`"
> ```
>
> monoconf script
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> import subprocess
> output = >subprocess.check_output(["/home/tag/.bin/mon.ls"])
> output = [ item.split() for item in >output.split("\n") ]
>
> mons = {}
>
> for mon in output:
>    if len(mon) > 0:
>        if mon[1] == "connected":
>            res=mon[2]
>            res=res.split("x")
>            for item in res[1].split("+"):
>                res.append(item)
>            res.pop(1)
>            mons[mon[0]] = res
>
> BOTTOM_LEFT = "LVDS1"
> TOP_RIGHT="VGA1"
>
> LEFT_WIDTH  = mons[BOTTOM_LEFT][0]
> LEFT_HEIGHT = mons[BOTTOM_LEFT][1]
>
> RIGHT_WIDTH  = mons[TOP_RIGHT][0]
> RIGHT_HEIGHT = mons[TOP_RIGHT][1]
>
> print "xrandr --output %s --pos 0x%s" % (
>    BOTTOM_LEFT,
>    (int(RIGHT_HEIGHT) - int(LEFT_HEIGHT)))
> print "xrandr --output %s --pos %sx0" % (
>    TOP_RIGHT,
>    int(LEFT_WIDTH)
> )
> ```
>
> and the mon.ls command
>
> ```
> xrandr -q | grep "^[^\ ].*" | grep -v Screen
> ```
>
> All of this is super hacky, but it works