# xrandr set offset to monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, xrandr

I've read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/485120/how-do-i-align-the-bottom-edges-of-two-monitors-with-xrandr), it's not helping.

I have two monitors, a 1920x1200 (DP-1), and a 1920x1080 (eDP-1) below *and a bit to the side* of the previous one.

`xrandr`'s man page and some online reading made me believe that I could offset the bottom monitor with the option `--pos`.

This however:

```
xrandr --output DP-1 --above eDP-1 --auto --primary --pos 0x0 --output eDP-1 --pos 940x1200
```

does not seem to add the x-offset to eDP-1.

Adding the `--verbose` flag confirms this, I get:

```
crtc 0:    1920x1200  59.95 +0+0 "DP-1"
crtc 1:    1920x1080  59.93 +0+1200 "eDP-1"
```

x-offset is 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the `--above`, `--below`, `--right-of`, and `--left-of` options are not compatible with `--pos`.

Apparently, `--pos` has lower precedence and the other ones take over (a warning would have been nice).

Modifying my command and removing the `--above` portion works:

```
$ xrandr  --output DP-1 --auto --primary --pos 0x0 --output eDP-1 --pos 940x1200  --verbose
screen 0: 2860x2280 755x602 mm  96.20dpi
crtc 0:    1920x1200  59.95 +0+0 "DP-1"
crtc 1:    1920x1080  59.93 +940+1200 "eDP-1"
```