# xrandr: aligned bottoms of monitors with rotation => mouse / artifact issues

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xorg, xrandr

I used the solutions in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/485120/how-do-i-align-the-bottom-edges-of-two-monitors-with-xrandr) to align my two monitors. My left monitor is High DPI 3840x2160 while the right is scaled 2x from 2560x1440 and rotated to portrait mode; they share a bottom edge.

`xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1x1 --mode 3840x2160 --pos 0x2800 --primary --output DP1 --scale 2x2 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 3840x0 --rotate left`

This works but has the following undesirable characteristics:

1. There's some artifacts when dragging windows -- they leave a black trail over the background.
2. The mouse pointer disappears when it gets within around 100px of the right edge of the right monitor. It still functions as a pointer but I cannot see it.

Any ideas for how I can correct these issues?

Graphics card is reported as "Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630"

Comment: Can you specify your linux distro/version?
Does issue #1 appear when having only one monitor active? And #2?

Comment: Related? https://askubuntu.com/questions/875246/xrandr-scaling-and-mouse-issue

Answer (score 0):

I have almost exactly the same issue. And I know of 2 workarounds:

1. Use modesetting x11 driver instead of Intel;
2. Set a smaller mouse cursor size.

My preferred workaround is the 2nd one.

Just set in `.Xresources`

```
Xcursor.size: <size>
```

40 or less worked for me.